# Symfony 4 not being able to autowave Entity from the argument type-hint

Tags: symfony

I have a simple twig template that is listing some tasks from the databse.

```
{% for task in tasks %}
            <li {% if task.status %} class="checked" {% endif %}>
                <a href="{{path('switch_status', {'id':task.id})}}">
                    <span class="task-list-item">{{task.title|escape('html')}}
                    </span>
                </a>
                <a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete?')" href="{{ path('task_delete', {'id':task.id}) }}">
                    <span class="close">X</span>
                </a>
            </li>
{% endfor %}
```

And i simple controller to delete that task

```
    /**
     * @Route("/delete/{id}", name="task_delete")
    */
    public function task_delete(Task $id): Response
    {
        $entitiyManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entitiyManager->remove($id);
        $entitiyManager->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('index'); 
    }
```

When i click on the delete i get the following error

App\Controller\ToDoListController::task_delete(): Argument #1 ($id) must be of type App\Entity\Task, string given, called in D:\Career\Learn\Symfony\Udemy\Robert Apollo - Beginner To Advanced\2. First App in Symfony\my_project\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\HttpKernel.php on line 169

Where could the error be?

Answer (score 1):

What is your annotation in function? It should be like the below:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
* @Route(path="/delete/{id}", name="task_delete")
* @return Response
*/
public function task_delete(Task $id): Response
{
    $entitiyManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entitiyManager->remove($id);
    $entitiyManager->flush();
    return $this->redirectToRoute('index'); 
}
```

Comment: I have them all
use App\Entity\Task;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

Comment: @Dime - There is an edit button under your question.  Consider using it to update your posted controller code with annotations.  Comments don't format well.  And it is not the use statements that are needed, it is the actual annotations that are of interest.  Bit off-topic but an ancient udemy course might not be the best learning tool unless you need to support ancient Symfony projects.

Comment: Yes sorry, I have the annotations above the method. And unfortunately yes, there is a project made in symphony 4 that I would have to maintain for some time.

Comment: @Dime You might want to make sure your management knows that [4.4 support](https://symfony.com/releases#symfony-releases-calendar) goes away at then end of 2023.  Maybe you can get a bit of funding to start looking at a migration.  Lots of good stuff in the current versions.

Comment: Thanks, do you know some good courses or books to learn new symphony version ? Also if you might know some books or courses on php performance optimization, that would be really nice to know.

Comment: @Dime I would suggest a Symfony website document for learning everything. It is well-maintained https://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I did not install the package annotations, after i run

composer require annotations

It started to work. I am sorry I wasted your time.